# Python - Adding new class/function to oauth/oauth2

Tags: python, oauth, sha256, sha1, hmac

Following a previous problem I had regarding upgrading SHA1 to SHA256 for a NetSuite API, one of the steps I need to take seems to be adding the following class:

```
SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA256
```

As well as updating the hmac.new function contain sha256.

```
hashed = hmac.new(key, raw, sha256)
```

What I'm asking about however is where to access said Python's libraries, and which file(s) to open to add new classes and functions to them.

Answer (score 0):

1.- Install the library oauth2

> pip install oauth2

2.- Go to the `__init__.py` of that module, on windows:

```
C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\oauth2\__init__.py
```

3.- Look at this line:

```
from hashlib import sha1
```

Replace it by:

```
from hashlib import sha1,sha256
```

4.- Look at this line:

```
def generate_nonce(length=8):
```

Below this function add a new one:

```
def generate_nonce(length=11):
    """Generate pseudorandom number."""
    return ''.join([str(random.SystemRandom().randint(0, 9)) for i in range(length)])
```

5.- At the end of the file add this class too:

```
class SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA256(SignatureMethod):
    name = 'HMAC-SHA256'
    def signing_base(self, request, consumer, token):
        if (not hasattr(request, 'normalized_url') or request.normalized_url is None):
            raise ValueError("Base URL for request is not set.")
        sig = (
            escape(request.method),
            escape(request.normalized_url),
            escape(request.get_normalized_parameters()),
        )
        key = '%s&' % escape(consumer.secret)
        if token:
            key += escape(token.secret)
        raw = '&'.join(sig)
        return key.encode('ascii'), raw.encode('ascii')
    def sign(self, request, consumer, token):
        """Builds the base signature string."""
        key, raw = self.signing_base(request, consumer, token)
        hashed = hmac.new(key, raw, sha256)
        # Calculate the digest base 64.
        return binascii.b2a_base64(hashed.digest())[:-1]
```